# Prevent content files to be added on Nuget restore

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec

We have some executables which we need to create our setups. So we have packed 
 the external dependencies  which are some .exe files into a nuget package. But on NuGet restore they are added to project root.

How can we achieve this ?

Have searched around but haven't found any solution so far.

Since we use nuspec file, this is what i have it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
 <metadata>
<id>VCRedistributable</id>
<version>$version$</version>
<title>VCRedistributable</title>
<authors>--</authors>
<owners>--</owners>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<description>InstallVCRedistributable assemblies</description>
<contentFiles>
    <files include="**" exclude="**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="false" 
 />
</contentFiles>
</metadata>

<files>
  <file src="VC\x86\*.*" target="content\x86" />
  <file src="VC\x64\*.*" target="content\x64" />
</files>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prevent content files to be added on Nuget restore

You should target to the **tools** folder instead of `content` folder.

So, your .nupsec file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
 <metadata>
   <id>VCRedistributable</id>
   <version>$version$</version>
   <title>VCRedistributable</title>
   <authors>--</authors>
   <owners>--</owners>
   <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
   <description>InstallVCRedistributable assemblies</description>

  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="VC\x86\*.*" target="tools\x86" />
    <file src="VC\x64\*.*" target="tools\x64" />
  </files>
</package>
```

That because the content directory is a convention-based working directory, which contents are copied to the project root:

[Convention-based working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory):

[image]

Besides, if you nuget package just include external some `.exe` files, you do not have to add the `contentFiles` label, this label is used for the content file for `packagereference`.

```
<contentFiles>
    <files include="**" exclude="**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="false" 
 />
</contentFiles>
```

If you are interested in, you can check [this document](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) for some more details.

**Update:**

> Is it good convention to create our own folder structure other than
>   NuGet defined since based on the tools folder description from above
>   it seems they will be accessible via Package Manager Console.

Of course, you can use your own folder structure other than NuGet defined. But you need to notice that there will be a limit to do this. **You can NOT just include your own folder structure, you need also need add a NuGet defined folder structure in your `.nuspec`**, otherwise, nuget will install failed with the error like:

> Could not install package 'MyCustomPackage 1.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

Because nuget did not detect that you added assembly references or content files to the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to cross check. Is it good convention to create our own folder structure other than  NuGet defined since based on the tools folder description from above it seems they will be accessible via Package Manager Console. We do not wish to have any reference to them rather than just be available in the NuGet package.

Comment: @Dave23Rave, Of course, you can. But there will be a limit to do this. Check my update answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. That resolves the confusion and helps me understand things better.